# Probability Jury Problem

Tags: probability, birthday

A bailiff who works in the court system asks 12-person juries when they are first sequestered, to break the ice, to play the following game. The jurors sit around a circular table that could be thought of as a clock, with the fore-man (fore-woman) sitting at position 12, and the other 11 jurors, in clockwise order, sitting in positions 1, 2, …, 11. Each juror is asked to write the month of his/her birthday with a marker on a sheet of paper and put it face-down on the table. The bailiff first turns over the sheet of paper with the fore-person's month on it. The jurors proceed around the room, in order, turning over their sheets of paper until a month's name is repeated. The juror who turns over the sheet where a repeat first occurs wins a prize. The only way the fore-person can win is if the jurors make it all the way around the table with no repeats (i.e. all 12 months show up exactly once). The bailiff asks the jurors, before they play, which position is most likely to win. Here are some of the answers which he has received over the years. Do you think any are correct? How would you explain?

(a) All 12 positions are equally likely to win.
(b) Position 1 is the best, and chances decrease monotonically from there.
(c) Position 6 is the best because it is in the middle of the first 11.
(d) Position 3 is best.
(e) Position 4 is best.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please show your attempt on this problem and you will be more likely to receive constructive feedback and answers to your question.

Comment: I don't know how to calculate which one has a better chance to have the same birthday. This is similar to the birthday paradox, slightly changed.

Comment: Hint: this is only superficially similar to the birthday paradox.  E.g. can you calculate the exact probability that position $1$ wins?  That should be easy.  Then can you calculate the exact prob that position $2$ wins (note that $1$ has to not win for this to happen)?  That's a little more difficult but still doable.  You need to do this for all positions and find the best one.

Comment: So, following your hint, I should do something like this:
-for the first one: 1/11 = 0.090
-for the second one: (1/11)*(2/11)
-for the third one: (1/11)*(2/11)*(3/11)

and like that until a reach the end?

Answer (score 2):

Let $N$ denote the winning position.  Then for $n=0,1,\ldots, 12,$ $$\begin{align*}P(N > n) &= \text{probability that none of the first } n+1 \text{ birthday months match} \\ &= \frac{12}{12}\cdot\frac{11}{12} \cdots \frac{12-n}{12} \\ &= \frac{12!(12-n)}{12^{n+1}(12-n)!} \left(=\frac{12!}{12^{n+1}(11-n)!} \text{ if } n\neq 12\right)\end{align*}$$

Then for $n=1,2,\ldots,12,$ $$\begin{align*}P(N=n) &= P(N>n-1) - P(N>n) \\ &= \frac{12!}{12^n(12-n)!} - \frac{12!(12-n)}{12^{n+1}(12-n)!} \\ &= \frac{12!\cdot n}{12^{n+1}(12-n)!} \end{align*}$$

[From here on, I'll write $P(n)$ as a shorthand for $P(N=n)$]

Therefore, for $n=1,2,\ldots,11,$ $$P(n+1) = \frac{(n+1)(12-n)}{12n}\cdot P(n)$$

Therefore, for $1\leq n \leq 11,$ $$\begin{align*}P(n+1) \left\{\begin{array}{c}< \\ = \\ >\end{array}\right\} P(n) &\iff \frac{(n+1)(12-n)}{12n} \left\{\begin{array}{c}< \\ = \\ >\end{array}\right\} 1 \\ &\iff (4+n)(3-n) \left\{\begin{array}{c}< \\ = \\ >\end{array}\right\} 0 \end{align*}$$

This allows us to see that
$$P(1) < P(2) < P(3) = P(4) > P(5) > P(6) > \ldots > P(12)$$
so that positions $3$ and $4$ are equally likely to be the winning positions, and they are the best two positions.

Comment: In the formula for $P(n)$, maybe you want one more power of $12$ in the denominator? Try it for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: @Ned Right.  Thanks for pointing that out.  It occurred as a result of re-indexing several times as I wrote the solution and I never updated the first line.  In any case, it doesn't affect anything after my change of notation, so the result still holds, but I'll fix the appropriate lines.

Comment: Theres any way we can calculate this on R?

Comment: @manuelarango "On R" as in real numbers?  If so, then I should point out that all my calculations _are_ over $\mathbb{R}.$  If instead you're asking whether the calculations can be done numerically, then the answer again is "Yes."  Just evaluate the first two formulas I gave for all the given values of $n.$  However, we necessarily will have to worry about round-off errors doing it this way, so while you're likely to correctly determine $P(1) < P(2) < P(3)$ and $P(4) > P(5) > \ldots,$ there's no guarantee you'll be able to conclude $P(3) = P(4).$

Comment: +1 for the comment about $\mathbb{R}$ (reals) vs $\mathsf{R}$ (programming language) :)

Answer (score 0):

You asked about how to find this in R

You could do something like:

```
twelve <- 12
probwin <- numeric(twelve)
for (n in 1:twelve){
  if(n == 1){
    probwin[n] <- 1 / twelve
  }else{
    probwin[n] <- (1 - sum(probwin[1:(n-1)])) * n / twelve 
  }
}
probwin
```

which would give

```
 [1] 8.333333e-02 1.527778e-01 1.909722e-01 1.909722e-01 1.591435e-01
 [6] 1.114005e-01 6.498360e-02 3.094457e-02 1.160421e-02 3.223393e-03
[11] 5.909554e-04 5.372322e-05
```

though the one line corresponding to $\frac{12!\, n}{(12-n)!\, 12^{n+1}}$

```
(1:12) * factorial(12) / factorial(12-(1:12)) / 12^((1:12)+1)
```

should give the same result.

By inspection, the third and fourth positions are both best with probability $\frac{55}{288}$, though using the `which.max` function in R would probably only identify one of these due to floating point precision issues